# How do I solve this numerical puzzle? 6*3*5 = 183033, so 8*2*9 =?

Tags: mathematics, pattern, calculation-puzzle

I am trying to answer this numerical puzzle - which of the five potential answers is correct, and why?

> 6*3*5 = 183033
> 5*4*3 = 201532
> 7*2*7 = 144928
> 8*2*9 = ?

Possible answers:

- A) 177335
- B) 167230
- C) 167234
- D) 187435
- E) 161872

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 6*3*5 = 183033

> 6*3 = 18; 6*5 = 30; 6*3 + 3*5 = 33
>  Put these together to get 183033

Solve the others with the same logic

Answer (score 2):

> C

Explanation:

> lets say source is A*B*C

.

> Result is: {AB}{AC}{B(A+C)}